# MPI - mpirun noticed that process... exited on signal 6

Tags: c++, signals, mpi, sigabrt

```
int proc_cnt, rank;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_cnt);

if (rank == 0) {
    std::vector<int> segment_ids = read_segment_ids(argv[kParDataIx]);
    std::map<int, ParameterSet> computed_par_sets;

    int buf_send[kBufMsToSlSize];
    double buf_recv[kBufSlToMsSize];
    MPI_Status status;

    int curr_segment_ix = 0;
    int recv_par_sets = 0;

    //inits workers
    for (int i = 1; i < proc_cnt; i++) {
        buf_send[0] = segment_ids[curr_segment_ix++];
        MPI_Send(
                buf_send, kBufMsToSlSize * sizeof (int), MPI_INT,
                i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    //sends slaves what to do and receives answers
    while(recv_par_sets < segment_ids.size()) {
        //receives answer
        MPI_Recv(buf_recv, kBufSlToMsSize * sizeof (double), MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        recv_par_sets++;

        if (curr_segment_ix < segment_ids.size()) {
            //there are still segments to process
            buf_send[0] = segment_ids[curr_segment_ix++];
        } else {
            //there is no segment to process, sends to slave termination char
            buf_send[0] = -1;
        }
        //sends back to source which segment to process as next
        MPI_Send(
                buf_send, kBufMsToSlSize * sizeof (int), MPI_INT,
                status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  

        std::pair<int,ParameterSet> computed_seg_par_set = convert_array_to_seg_par_set(buf_recv);
        computed_par_sets.insert(computed_seg_par_set);
    }

    print_parameter_sets(computed_par_sets);
    std::cout << "[Master] was termianted" << std::endl;
} else {

    int bufToSl[kBufMsToSlSize];
    double bufToMs[kBufSlToMsSize];

    Bounds bounds = read_bounds_file(argv[kParBoundsIx]);
    Config config = read_config_file(kConfigFileName);

    while (true) {
        MPI_Recv(bufToSl, kBufMsToSlSize * sizeof (int), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
        int segment_id = bufToSl[0];

        if (segment_id == -1) {
            //termination character was found
            break;
        }

        Segment segment = read_segment(argv[kParDataIx], segment_id);
        std::map<int, Segment> segment_map;
        segment_map.insert(std::pair<int, Segment>(segment.GetId(), segment));

        SimplexComputer simplex_computer(segment_map, bounds, config);
        ParameterSet par_set = simplex_computer.ComputeSegment(&segment);
        convert_seg_par_set_to_array(segment_id, par_set, bufToMs);

        MPI_Send(
                bufToMs, kBufSlToMsSize * sizeof (double), MPI_DOUBLE,
                0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    std::cout << "[SLAVE] " << rank << " was terminated" << std::endl;

}

MPI_Finalize();
```

I just don't get it. When I try to run this with mpirun and process count set to 5, all processes finish, control outputs saying that master or slave was terminated are printed, but in the end there is this statement:

mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 1534 on node Jan-MacBook exited on signal 6 (Abort trap: 6).

What am I doing wrong? Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to both Send and Recv definitions, the second parameter *count* is a number of elements you're sending or receiving. Datatype of those elements is then specified as a third parameter of both calls:

```
int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
```

and the same goes for Recv:

```
int MPI_Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)
```

You can find defitions here: [Send](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Send.3.php) and [Recv](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Recv.3.php).

Hope it helps.